# Which register should be used to store the count?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I am writing the code for the following program,

### Objective:

Count the number of spaces pressed by the user. Break if enter is pressed.

### Code:

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100H
.DATA
    TEXT DB "Enter Character"
.CODE
    MOV AX,9
    MOV DX,TEXT
    INT 21H
    BACK:
        INT21H
        CMP AL, " "
        JE INCREMENT
        CMP AL, "\n"
        JE OUT
        JMP BACK
INCREMENT:
        INC ; which register do I use here? I feel that I am out of registers
        LOOP BACK
OUT:
;display the count
```

In the above code, I have marked the area where I am feeling that I don't have anymore registers left to use. I have to use `AX`,`AL`,`DX`,`DL` registers in the code. Which other register can I use to store the count? Please help, thanks.

Comment: Clue: what letters come between A and D in the alphabet ?

Comment: "Ethical" ? Start with: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8086#Registers_and_instructions and maybe consider reading an introductory book on x86 asm programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the following general-purpose registers that you can use:

`AX` (`AH` is 8 most significant bits of `AX`, `AL` is 8 least significant bits of `AX`)
`BX` (`BH` is 8 MSBs of `BX`, `BL`is 8 LSBs of `BX`)
`CX` (`CH` is 8 MSBs of `CX`, `CL` is 8 LSBs of `CX`)
`DX` (`DH` is 8 MSBs of `DX`, `DL` is 8 LSBs of `DX`)
`BP` (individual halves aren't accessible directly)
`SI` (individual halves aren't accessible directly)
`DI` (individual halves aren't accessible directly)

Btw, you have to set `AH` to 1 before `int 21H` that reads a character into `AL` from the keyboard.

And your text string must end with a dollar sign if you want to print it using `int 21H` function 9.

Also, Enter's code is 13 ('\r'), not 10 ('\n').

A few more issues:

- Your stack is too small for interrupts. Bump it up to 4 KB. If you don't, they'll overwrite some code or data in your program or in some other place. You don't want that.
- Since this is an .EXE program (and not .COM) you must set `DS` to point to the data segment. See your book or notes or assembler documentation on how to do that. `ES` should probably be set to the same value.